# To find approximate DOB based on age and a date column

Tags: python

I have three columns in a data frame: start_date, age and DOB.
But some of the DOB information is missing, while start_date and age are not. I wish to impute the empty cells of DOB column, with an approximate DOB, using the formula: start_date - age.

An example of the data frame:

```
start_date  |  age   |  DOB

3/1/2017      87          11/1/1930

9/13/2017     31

7/26/2017     60

7/26/2017     52

4/1/2017      37          12/14/1979
```

My question is how to execute this, only on the empty cells of the DOB column of the data frame?
Is there any easy way?

Thanks and regards

Comment: I would **not** recommend putting that data in the database, as it's difficult to communicate which rows are actual DoBs and which ones are assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do that:

```
df.DOB = pd.to_datetime(df.DOB)

estimated_dob = pd.to_datetime(df.start_date) - pd.to_timedelta(df.age, unit='y') 
df.loc[df.DOB.isna(), "DOB"] = estimated_dob[df.DOB.isna()]

#to remove the time part of the timestamp: 

df["DOB"] = df["DOB"].dt.date
```

The result is:

```
  start_date  age         DOB
0   3/1/2017   87  1930-11-01
1  9/13/2017   31  1986-09-13
2  7/26/2017   60  1957-07-26
3  7/26/2017   52  1965-07-26
4   4/1/2017   37  1979-12-14
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I get the DOB column without  timestamp?

Comment: Edited the post. let me know if it answers the question.